# Preprocessing for wildcarded Snakemake rules

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a Snakemake recipe which contains a very expensive preparatory step, common for all its calls.  Here is a pseudorule for demonstration sake:

```
rule sample:
    input:
        "{name}.config"
    output:
        "{name}.npz"
    run:
        import somemodule
        
        data = somemodule.Loader("some_big_data")  # expensive
        np.savez(output, data.process(input))  # also expensive
```

At the moment `data` is loaded *de novo* for every target, which is pretty suboptimal.  How can I make it to be loaded only once?

I look for something which allows to rewrite the rule like that:

```
rule sample:
    input:
        "{name}.config"
    output:
        "{name}.npz"
    setup:
        import somemodule
        
        data = somemodule.Loader("some_big_data")  # expensive
    run:
        np.savez(output, data.process(input))  # also expensive
```

or:

```
rule sample:
    input:
        "{name}.config"
    output:
        "{name}.npz"
    run:
        import somemodule

        data = somemodule.Loader("some_big_data")  # expensive
        
        for job in jobs:
            np.savez(job.output,
                     data.process(job.input))  # also expensive
```

[In another question I have described the code `Loader.__init__()` is based on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694729/how-can-i-load-fenics-objects-faster).

Comment: You could load it outside the rule and then pass it as a `param`?

Comment: @MichaelHal I am not sure if I got what you mean, but wouldn't that make it load the data every time I call `snakemake` (even if there is nothing to do)?

Comment: Yes, that is true. The only other way I can think of speeding this up is by improving the speed of the `somemodule.Loader` function. Does it just load a file into memory? Or does it load a file and do some processing on the file contents before returning `data`?

Comment: @MichaelHall it loads [_FEniCS_](https://fenicsproject.org/)' mesh and related objects (`FunctionSpace`, `MeshFunctionSizet`), which are used by the `.process()` method to solve equation parametrized by the input file. I think there is a lot of processing than just reading the binary data.

Comment: @MichaelHall If you are interested in the most important code from the constructor, please see my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694729/how-can-i-load-fenics-objects-faster

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to create a pickled object with the data of interest. Please research the [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) of using pickled objects to check that it is acceptable for your case. If it is, then it would be along the following lines:

```py
rule sample:
    input:
        "{name}.config"
    output:
        pickle = "{name}.pickle",
    run:
        import somemodule
        import pickle
        
        data = somemodule.Loader("some_big_data")  # expensive
        pickle.dump(pickle, output.pickle)
```

In downstream rules you would reference the pickled file like any other file, just making sure to load it with `pickle.load`.

Comment: Sadly, objects are not pickleable (`TypeError: can't pickle dolfin.cpp.mesh.Mesh objects`).

Comment: Hmm, can you try `cloudpickle` (https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle)?